# The proof of Hahn Decomposition Theorem in Folland (real analysis)

Tags: real-analysis

On p.86, the following is Folland's proof of Hahn:

[image]
[image]

Before the red line, it is not hard to understand and I think the proof is enough for showing $N$ is negative. Since it proves that:

> $N$ cannot contain any nonnull positive sets.

Why would Folland continue to prove $N$ negative after the red line?
Is it not enough to prove it before the red line?

And can anyone explain the **logic** Folland used after the red line? (I read many times and cannot fully understand what he want to say.)

(In some lecture from youtube, I even see some professor proving Hahn just following the part before red line.)

Comment: Why is the proof before the red line enough?  In the paragraph before the red line, he is beginning to prove that any subset of $N$ cannot have positive measure.  Since we assume $N$ is not negative, there must be a subset of positive measure, which is $A$.  Then we can find $B$ a subset of $A$ with larger measure than $A$.  That's now where the red line is, and it doesn't finish the proof $N$ must be negative. We haven't found a contradiction yet.

Comment: I just re-read through your question again.  I think you might be having trouble understanding the difference between a **positive set** and a **set of positive measure**.  A set $A$ of positive measure is a set satisfying $\nu(A) \geq 0$.  A **positive set** $A$ is a set satisfying: for all measurable $E \subseteq A$, we have $\nu(E) \geq 0$ (i.e., every measurable subset of $A$ has positive measure).

Comment: Now, when he is proving that $N$ must be a negative set, i.e., that every subset of $N$ must have negative measure, he does so in 2 steps: 1. He proves that $N$ cannot have any *positive sets* other than null sets.  In other words, if $B$ is a subset of $N$ such that for every $E \subseteq B$, $\nu(E) \geq 0$, then $B$ must be a null set.

Comment: Proving that $N$ has no non-null positive subsets is not enough to prove $N$ is a negative set.  To prove $N$ is a negative set, you need to show every subset has negative measure.  In other words, no subset can have positive measure.  He didn't prove that in the first step.  He proved no non-null subset can be a *positive set*, which is different than no subset can have positive measure.

Comment: Ok, good.  I just want to repeat one more time so that I am as concise as possible.  You need to prove $N$ is a negative set.  So you need to prove every measurable subset of $N$ has negative measure.  Ok, well, first he proves 1, that no subset of $N$ that is not a null set can be a *positive set*.  Which means no non-null subset can have all of its subsets having positive measure. Then he proves 2, that $N$ itself is a negative set, i.e., has every subset having negative measure.